# download audios in Book

Tags: download

I am making an Application consisting of Book inwhich i have added the Images of each line and i want that when i do focus on particular line then the respective audio is played, So if i have 7 lines on one page then i have to download 7 audios from server and currently i am using this approach, So Please suggest me because i have to work on entire book and what is the best way to download audios.

Comment: I am working on Blackberry JDE.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative Approach will be to use a **Text to Speech** engine like [Festival](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/).

IMHO - Downloading each line's audio from the server I think is an Overkill. But that's just me.. :)